# Simulating a long keypress in python

Tags: python, windows, keyboard

Is there a way to simulate a long keypress in python?
I tried with SendKies and win32api, with no luck. I would like to keep using python
2.5 or 2.6, because i also need the pybluez module. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Something I have done to simulate a longer key press is use a time.sleep(amountoftime) between the key press and key release.